# How do you rollback to a previous Gemfile.Lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, version-control

I recently ran 'bundle update,' and it updated the Twitter-bootstrap-rails gem to the latest version. Ever since then, the header size has changed, and I would like to roll back to the previous gem versions for all my gems.

I tried rolling back to my previous gemfile and bundle updating, but the problem was I didn't specify versions in my gemfile so it doesn't know to degrade a version. I also tried checking the specific previous version and specifying that, but I think all the dependencies changed as well.

So I need to find a way to just go back to using all the old versions, which seems to be stored in the Gemfile.lock file. How would I do this?

Comment: Was Gemfile.lock added to your git repo?  If so, just roll it back to the checkin prior to the update.  That will give you the version numbers you should use in your Gemfile.

Comment: Yes, I am using Git, and I can see all the versions that I used that date, but how do I actually tell Rails to go back to all those previous versions? I want to keep my code, and just downgrade all my gems to that date. The problem with just rolling back with git is I didn't specify the versions for each gem, so it would just update every gem to the newest one if I run 'bundle update'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily go back to a version of any file that you track in git with

```
git checkout <some-ref> -- path/to/your/file
```

where some-ref is

```
HEAD^
HEAD~5
v1.2
some-branch
```

etc

Comment: That will check out the old version. Don't forget to make a new commit afterwards with `git commit Gemfile.lock`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, if you're using git is as follows

```
git checkout -- Gemfile.lock
```