# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Exercise 3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am new to coding and stackoverflow.com. I have been following along ruby.railstutorial.org and was feeling pretty good when I tackled the advanced exercise in section 3.5 (replacing sqlite3 with pg gems through postgresql).

I changed my Gemfile from:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

to

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I also changed my database.yml file from:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

to include password/port and with pg postgresql isntead of sqlite3.
I installed pgadmin III and postgresql 9.2
I bundle update and installed some pg gems and ran my:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

which stopped working even though it was working right before all these changes.
These are the error messages:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in 'require': cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in ''

and about 30 more similar to those. I tried searching on here for some similar issues and couldn't find any, realized I was in over my head for "advanced" and tried to revert back all my changes.

I changed my gemfile back to original and my database.yml file back and tried running again but I am still getting the exact same message.

Any advice would be very helpful. I am very new to this.

Comment: Did you run `bundle` after changing your Gemfile?

Comment: Yea I ran bundle update and bundle install

Comment: `bundle update` will update *everything* in your Gemfile, you probably don't want to get in a habit of doing that every time.  Looks like bundler issues since gems can't find other gems...

Comment: Try to give a descriptive title that goes to the core of your issue. Right now, it looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: thank you. any suggestion to change it back so I can continue the tutorial?

Comment: If your file was under version control system, then you can use it in order to rollback the unwanted changes in Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unsafe to run bundle update because this command update **all** your gems , and new versions of gems could break your application, this is what was happens when you are doing `bundle update`, i suggest for you [this article](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update/) to understand more about bundle update command.

I think you use Git ? if yes what about return to previous commit you are already doing ?

```
git reset --hard commit_name
```

so an example of this is :

```
git reset --hard f460cb......
```

**commit name** can be found using command:

```
git log
```

**another solution i think more convenient** is to restore your old Gemfile.lock (Gemfile.lock is the file which contains your old gems versions and dependencies of each gem). you can find how to do this here [How do you rollback to a previous Gemfile.Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105201/how-do-you-rollback-to-a-previous-gemfile-lock)

Comment: @user2733938 if this help you to solve your problem click on the validation icon at left from this answer

Comment: I had the same problem as TOS: boldly charging on to move my app to a postgresql db, then totally messing everything up and having to figure out how to fix it. If only the tutorial had reminded us to "Fork the Repo" first, then like a tough crossword puzzle, supply  the solution in the back of the book.